# Import Get-ADReplicationStie into an Array

Tags: powershell, active-directory-group

I've looked and I've been banging my head against the wall. I'm sure it's probably something simple that I'm missing. I am trying to import a list of AD Sites into the Array that populates ComboBox1 but I can't get it to work.

I've written this code to create a form that has 2 Combo Boxes. The First combo box needs to be 
    populated based on the Array created by the Get-ADReplicationSite value. In my Lab I have 5 test 
    sites.
     If I have the sites Hardcoded, it works fins however
     if I try to create the array from the Get-AD, I am not able to get the array to show up properly in 
    ComboBox 1.

```
####################################################################################################    
#####   This is the section that I use to Create the Arrays
####################################################################################################

## This piece of code works
# If you want to have the sites Hardcoded, use this line
#>
$ADSites=@("S01","S02","S03")

## I can't get this to work
# $ADSites= Get-ADReplicationSite -Filter * | select Description

# Below is a list of Variables that are hard coded. I'm going to convert this to an import of a CSV file
$ADSiteS01=@("AAA","BBB","CCC")
$ADSiteS02=@("DDD","EEE","FFF")
$ADSiteS03=@("GGG","HHH","JJJ")
$ADSiteS04=@("KKK","LLL","MMM")
$ADSiteS05=@("NNN","PPP","QQQ")
```

I can create the form and the combo boxes. Right now I am struggling with getting the AD information into an Array and using the Array to populate the First Combo Box which will read the above hard coded variables

```
 ##################################################################################################
    #####   Now we do stuff
    #### The form keeps asking me to add details so I'm adding details
    ##################################################################################################

    # Populate Combobox 2 When Combobox 1 changes
    $ComboBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged({
        $combobox2.Items.Clear() # Clear the list
        $combobox2.Text = $null  # Clear the current entry
    # Refresh ComboBox 1 changes    
        Switch ($ComboBox1.Text) {
                "S01"{

                $ADSiteS01 | ForEach { 
                    $combobox2.Items.Add($_)
                }
            }
    # Refresh ComboBox 1 changes    
                "S02"{
                $ADSiteS02 | ForEach {
                    $combobox2.Items.Add($_)
                 }
            }
    # Refresh ComboBox 1 changes    
            "S03"{
                $ADSiteS03 | ForEach {
                    $combobox2.Items.Add($_)
                  }
            }

        }
        $labelClub.Text = $combobox1.Text + "-" + $combobox2.Text + "-" + $textBoxFPS.Text
    })

    $ComboBox2.add_SelectedIndexChanged({
        $labelClub.Text = $combobox1.Text + "-" + $combobox2.Text + "-" + $textBoxFPS.Text
    })

    $textBoxFPS.add_TextChanged({
        $labelClub.Text = $combobox1.Text + "-" + $combobox2.Text + "-" + $textBoxFPS.Text
    })
```

This is where I create the Combo Boxes. I would put the whole script in however, the site won't let me and keeps asking for more explanation, even though the script is thoroughly documented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, this could fix your problem:

```
$ADSites = (Get-ADReplicationSite -filter *).Description
```

The difference is that this gives a list of strings (perfect for a combobox), as opposed to returning an object.

Comment: >One hiccup

    ##### Create Combo Boxes
    $Combobox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
    $Combobox1.Location = '26,25'
    $Combobox1.Size = '105,20'
    $Combobox1.items.AddRange($ADSites) # This is causing an error

> This is the Error that shows up
    Exception calling "AddRange" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null. 
    Parameter name: item"
    At Thought3.ps1:50 char:1
    + $Combobox1.items.AddRange($ADSites) 
    + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException + 
    FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException